# Development only with testing - no actually running - good practice?

Tags: java, testing

I just started in a new team. My task right now is to bring an old application to their new microservice framework (mostly Java). It runs in quite a complex environment, like consuming other web services, messaging via several queues, and providing an public API for other services to use.

The new thing for me is that their development process doesn't involve an actually running the application even once. Instead they solely do testing: unit tests and integration tests. For the integration tests they employ a couple of docker container that mimic their actual production system. There is no staging system - only the production system, where I have no access.

To me it feels weird to never actually run the application. **Is this common? Have you guys encountered the same? Is this considered a good practice?**

**Edit**: For the system it is not critical that it runs 24/7 without interruption. An outage after a new deployment is not nice but if monitored and handled (e.g. switch back to an older version) it's not a big problem.

Comment: Isn't this just mock testing, except with real instances?

Comment: I've never come across it, but presumably the proof is in the pudding: has the customer ever come across errors that the testing didn't find?  Also, what about errors that automated tests don't usually find, e.g. typos in messages.

Comment: @SteveSmith I should have added that it is not critical that the system is up 24/7. So an outage after a new deployment is not nice but if monitored and handled (e.g. switch back to an older version) it is okay

Comment: It sounds like the customer does the final testing then.